# Calculating RPM of the disk drive

Tags: storage, computer-architecture, disk-drive

Well I have a question about RPM of the disk drive.
I've seen an example where:

seek time of the HD: 5ms
track size: 5MB

If an application wants to read 1MB from the disk with a maximum time of 20ms (considering that the data is equally distributed over 3 different tracks), the RPM of the disk must be at least 20400.

I just ask myself why. Is there a mathematical formula to calculate it? How is it calculated?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is most likely a formula that works **in theory** however there are other factors (how fragmented is the disc, etc)

Comment: Seek time is not a constant; it is a ***non-linear*** function of the number of cylinders traversed.  Track size is not fixed for zone-bit recording (as used by all modern HDDs).

Answer (score 1):

If the data is equally distributed over 3 tracks, then you need 3 seeks. That will take 15ms. We want to read in 20ms, so we have 5ms left. We need the disk to make three complete rotations in those 5 milliseconds, one for each track. So the disk must do 3 rotations in 5 milliseconds. A minute is 60,000 milliseconds, so a disk that can do 3 rotations in 5 milliseconds can do 36,000 rotations in 60,000 milliseconds.

I don't know how 20,400 was calculated. I get 36,000 as shown above.

Comment: you don't consider that the application is going to read only 1MB. Is that correct? Do you really need three complete rotations?

Comment: I'm assuming we're supposed to be figuring the worst case. The worst case is that we get to each track just as we missed the last bit of data we needed and so have to wait for one full rotation. Maybe we're supposed to figure out the average case.

Comment: Actually you need an initial seek from somewhere of unspecified distance and duration, and then maybe two 1-cylinder seeks.  If the track is in the same cylinder,, then the seek time is zero, but the rotational latency still has to be figured out.  The problem is poorly worded.

Comment: @sawdust I agree. I'm assuming that the initial seek and the track-to-track seek take the same amount of time, which is not typical.